# Adding product using WooCommerce Rest Api - Stock issue

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to add a WooCommerce product from one Wordpress site to another using **WooCommerce Rest Api**. It's working in some case, but stock management and stock quantity are not working. here is code…

Client library:
https://packagist.org/packages/woothemes/woocommerce-api

Data:

```
    $data = [
       'name' => 'Premium Quality',
       'title' => 'test',
       'type' => 'simple',
       'manage_stock' => true,
       'stock_quantity' => 40,
       'regular_price' => '21.99',
       'description' => 'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.',
       'short_description' => 'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.',
];
```

Response:
I am getting empty response in **`manage_stock`** and **`stock_quantity`**.

Same thing happen when I change the product type to variation, it isn't working either if I update the data sent, according to WooCommerce Rest Api.

Comment: I got it to work by specifying `in_stock` field to true/false. `'in_stock' => $stock_quantity > 0`